# Parse.User.currentAsync() returns null

Tags: react-native, parse-platform, expo, back4app

I have an expo app. I'm using AsyncStorage from react-native.

The app is set up with Parse as follows:

```
import Parse from 'parse';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

Parse.initialize("r...", "2...");
Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';
Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage);
```

I can log in log out, etc fine.

But when I'm using 
Parse.User.currentAsync() after successful login, I get null as a response. This means I cannot re-use previous sessions and have to log in every time the app is launched.

I've added `Parse.User.enableUnsafeCurrentUser();` just before calling currentAsync() and login() as well, but makes no difference. I'm stuck.

Any idea why this is happening?

Many thanks

Comment: Looks like changing to import Parse from 'parse/react-native' made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've already solved it, but I'm sending the code which worked to me.

```
import React from 'react';
import Parse from 'parse/react-native';

Parse.initialize("APPLICATION_ID", "JAVASCRIPT_KEY");
Parse.serverURL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com";
Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage);
```

Screen.js

```
componentWillMount(){
  Parse.User.currentAsync().then(user => {
    if (user == undefined) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('LogInStack') 
    } else {
      let sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();
      /* ... */
    }
  });
}
```